# Visual Studio Code PHP White Text

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Dark+ (default dark) Theme: 
[image]

I want to ask, why does my Visual Studio Code only show white text.
Already install the extension, change the language to PHP at the right bottom and reload the app.

Still all white.

Thank you.

EDIT:
Image Light (Visual Studio) Theme
[image]

Comment: Changed it to Light (Visual Studio) Theme. See post for image.

Comment: Ah... I see what's going on. My php file doesn't have an openner. <?php. Thanks for the help..! Realized it after I read your link and see their code ! So this isn't a software issue, but a code issue haha